# Как извлечь переменную из файла phtml в модальное окно на jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Задачка - есть файл .phtml, в котором определяется значение функции ($code) и в нем же выводиться. Также в этом файле вызывается галерея(в модальном окне, плагин prettyPhoto). Необходимо получить значение этого $code  в модальном окне и вставить в соответствующее место.
1. Код из .phtml

```html
if (ISSET($prod['brands']) AND $prod['brands'] != NULL) {
    $attributes = $prod->getAttributes();
    $optId = $prod->getData('brands');
    $attributeAddLabel = $attributes['brands']->getFrontend()->getAttribute()->getSource();
    foreach ($attributeAddLabel->getAllOptions() AS $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $optId) {
            $code = $option['option_code'];
        }
    }
} else {
    $code = '';
```

2. Часть кода из плагина prettyPhoto

```js
    markup: '<div class="pp_pic_holder"> \
      <div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div> \
      <div class="pp_top"> \
       <div class="pp_left"></div> \
       <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
       <div class="pp_right"></div> \
      </div> \
      <div class="pp_content_container"> \
       <div class="pp_left"> \
       <div class="pp_right"> \
        <div class="pp_content"> \
         <div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div> \
         <div class="pp_fade"> \
          <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a> \
          <div class="manufacturer" style="bottom:30px;"></div>\
          <div id="fa-arrows"></div> \
          <div class="pp_details" > \
```

Значение $code  - это строка, которая вставляется как класс в

```html
<div class="manufacturer  {Сюда} " style="bottom:30px;"></div>\
```

Прошу помощи, т.к. не совсем специалист в js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, решение такое - 
1. В файле *.phtml добавляем

```html
<input type="hidden" id="current_brand" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" />
```

2. В файле-плагине PrettyPhoto добавляем

```html
$.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
  pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
   hook: 'rel', /* the attribute tag to use for prettyPhoto hooks. default: 'rel'. For HTML5, use "data-rel" or similar. */
   animation_speed: 'fast', /* fast/slow/normal */
   ajaxcallback: function() {},
   slideshow: false, /* false OR interval time in ms */
   autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */
   opacity: 0, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
   show_title: false, /* true/false */
   allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
   allow_expand: true, /* Allow the user to expand a resized image. true/false */
   default_width: 300,
   default_height: 244, 
   currentBrand:function() {  ///////наш код
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var q=jQuery('#current_brand').val();
    });
    return q;
   },
..............................................................
```

3. и в этом же плагине вызываем в нужном месте

```html
markup: '<div class="pp_pic_holder "> \
      <div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div> \
      <div class="pp_top"> \
       <div class="pp_left"></div> \
       <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
       <div class="pp_right"></div> \
      </div> \
      <div class="pp_content_container"> \
       <div class="pp_left"> \
       <div class="pp_right"> \
        <div class="pp_content product-view" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;"> \
         <div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div> \
         <div class="pp_fade"> \
          <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a> \
   <!--Здесь вызываем -->       <div class="manufacturer '+jQuery('#current_brand').val()+'" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;height: 78px;width: 230px;position: absolute;top: 400px;z-index: 1000;left: 50px;"></div>\
```

Answer (score 1):

Если $code глобальная переменная, то вывод в нужном месте:

```
<?= $code ?>
```

Для показа модального окна может подойти простейший alert, например:

```
<script language="javascript">alert("<?= $code ?>");</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Посмотрел - переменная $code - не глобальная. Чтобы было понятнее насчет модально окна - вот ссылка, где все происходит http://dev1.pragmacharts.com/damen/sonnenbrillen/test.html. На странице есть фото с картинкой бренда. Также должно быть в модальном окне (кликнуть на фото). Картинка вызывается через css, а код css -подтягивается как раз $code

Comment: Ну начнём с простого. Для того, чтобы плагин стал работать, то есть выводить окно - необходимо вставить тег '<a href="url большой картинки" rel="prettyPhoto">...</a>'. Взято из руководства по плагину.

теперь чтобы вывести переменную в класс: '<div class="manufacturer <? echo $code; ?>" style="bottom:30px;"></div>'

Comment: <div class="manufacturer <? echo $code; ?>" style="bottom:30px;"></div>   вот что выводит html

Comment: Плагин работает. Модальное окно тоже. Мне лишь необходимо вывести значение этой переменной в верстку, которая формируется в самом плагине

Comment: Вы говорили что всё находится в одном файле .phtml Именно в нём должен быть участок кода, который выводит переменную на страницу.

Comment: Возможно не точно описал. Да, эта переменная описывается и выводится одном файле .phtml в соответсвующем месте (ее значение - строка, для свойства css). В этом же файле вызывается в head плагин prettyPhoto.js , в котором зашита верстка модального окна с галереей. Мне необходимо вывести значение переменной $code в верстку этого модального окна в определенном месте. Да, задачка та еще.

Comment: Ну хорошо. Всё-равно вам надо в том файле сделать перенос информации о переменной в HTML часть. Как вариант вставить после подгрузки JQuery такой код:
    '<script>$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div.manufacturer").addClass("<? echo $code; ?>");
});</script>'
Повторюсь, это должно добавляться в файле .phtml, то есть там, где формируется переменная $code